# How to disable secure boot if I don't have Windows installed?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I can't install Windows on my laptop until I can go to BIOS and select appropriate SATA/AHCI (if I don't do this, an error fires during Win file expansion on my Dell XPS 9333).

I have managed to install Ubuntu but I am not able to go to UEFI firmware settings (Ubuntu is not configure with EFI).

What can I do? How can I access UEFI settings (BIOS) if I don't have Win installed? I have an Ubuntu installation and also a Win setup USB.

Comment: Can you get the Ubuntu USB boot in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to make any changes to your SATA mode (SATA/AHCI/RAID) to install Windows, though it is best to use AHCI with an SSD to allow Windows to use the SSD's TRIM functionality.

According to page 55 of your laptop's [Owner's Manual](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_xps_laptop/xps-13-9333_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf), enter your System Setup (BIOS/UEFI), then open the Boot screen (usually with the arrow keys), then arrow down to the Secure Boot option and set it to Disabled. You may also need to change the Boot List Option from UEFI to Legacy.

Lastly, though your Owner's Manual seems to use BIOS and UEFI to mean the same thing, [they are quite different](http://www.howtogeek.com/56958/). BIOS is the old, nearly obsolete version of System Setup that is usually only has a few basic colors and characters, while UEFI is the modern System Setup and often uses checkboxes and other graphical elements.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an operating system installed to access BIOS/UEFI nor does it matter which OS is currently installed. If you start tapping **F12** immediately after you turn your laptop on it should enter Dell's BIOS/UEFI menu. There will be a menu option for secure boot at left hand side.

Though I think you may be confused regarding UEFI's menus. There isn't a separate menu system for BIOS mode on UEFI motherboards. All of the settings in the UEFI menu apply to BIOS mode - unless specifically noted in the menu.